# Search in iTunes not working as expected

Tags: macos, mac, itunes

I have iTunes 9.0.1 running under OS X 10.6.1 on two computers - A Mac Pro and a Mac Mini.

On the Mac-Pro, I get the expected behavior when i search directly in song lists.

> Click on Music under LIBRARY
>
> Select All (Genres) All (Artists) All (Albums) in the iTunes 8 style top browser
>
> Click on the 'Name column' to sort songs alphabetically
>
> Then start typing, for instance "Hall", iTunes jumps directly to the first song that starts with 'Hall', in my case "Halleluja' by Charlie Parker.

On the Mac-Mini when I replicate the above, nothing happens. It looks like the Mac does not respond at all to my typing.  Searching the song using the search pane top-right works both on the Mac-Pro and the Mac Mini

Comment: could you be more precise or add screenshots, please?

Comment: I revised text and hope it is clearer now. i don't know yet how to add screenshots to my question, although i am afraid they will be boring in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know what was wrong but solved the problem after a clean install of snow leopard and a rebuilt of the library. Not subtle, but it worked

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the Name column, try selecting the first song in the list (to give the song list focus) before you begin typing the name of the song in.

Comment: Adam, thanks. I tried this but it has no effect.  iTunes just highlights the first song no matter what i type